# How to find the array indexes for each element in another array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

There are two arrays:

```
   A=[2,6,9,10];
   B=[6,10,9,2,2,9,10,10,6,6,2,9];
```

I want to output the following array:

```
   C=[2,4,3,1,1,3,4,4,2,2,1,3];
```

How to do this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, `[~,C]=ismember(B,A)`;

Answer (score 0):

My answer shall be  C=arrayfun(@(x) find(A==x),B)